# C# query to update textbox value from gridview double click event

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I have a simple form with 2 textboxes and a combo box and two radio buttons. values of these all items are saving into a database of SQL server 2008 and showing at the gridview which is placed in the same form. if a click any of the rows in gridview it returns all the values back into the form fields (above mentioned data fields). Now my question comes. I want to change the value of any field and update it by clicking the UPDATE button. How to do this please help me. my code behind update button is here but it doesn't work.

```
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection str_Conn = new SqlConnection("server=HOME; Database=TestProject; Integrated Security=sspi");
        str_Conn.Open();
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand str_Cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Personal_Info SET Name = '"+ txtBx_Name.Text +"' WHERE Name = '"+ txtBx_Name.Text.ToString() +"'", str_Conn);
        str_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        str_Conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This very unsafe code SQL Injections are possible i would recommend using parameters

Comment: you need to use `parameterized query for starters` also look up how to use `DataBinding` where in your code are you binding the data to the Gridview please when posting code on `SO`, show all relevant code also what is the purpose of this line `DataSet DS = new DataSet();` you are declaring something but never filling it nor using it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't update because you are using the updated field in the update statement which will not return any result. so try to get the old value and retain it in some variable and use that in the where clause of update statement

```
 SqlCommand str_Cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Personal_Info SET Name = '"+ txtBx_Name.Text +"' WHERE Name = '"+ txtBx_Name.Text.ToString() +"'", str_Conn);
```

Another big problem is this code is not secure and can be used to here is the [LINK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx)